Tailwind dropdown menu items don't popout from react nextjs card component
I have a dropdown menu component (DropdownWithSearch), but when I click it, it does not popout, but instead opens inside the card component(in UserAssignForm), where it is positioned.

DropdownWithSearch component
import { Menu, Transition } from '@headlessui/react';
import { Fragment, useState } from 'react';

type DropdownWithSearchProps = {
  users: string[];
};

const DropdownWithSearch = ({ users }: DropdownWithSearchProps) => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggleDropdown = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  const handleSearchChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setSearchTerm(event.target.value.toLowerCase());
  };

  const filteredUsers = users.filter((user) =>
    user.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
  );

  return (
    <Menu as="div" className="relative">
      <Menu.Button
        className="focus:outline-none inline-flex items-center gap-x-1 text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900"
      >
        <button
          onClick={toggleDropdown}
          className="focus:outline-none linear px-10 rounded-xl bg-brand-500 py-3 text-base font-medium text-white transition duration-200 hover:bg-brand-600 active:bg-brand-700 dark:bg-brand-400 dark:text-white dark:hover:bg-brand-300 dark:active:bg-brand-200"
        >
          Select Assignee
        </button>
      </Menu.Button>
      <Transition
        show={isOpen}
        as={Fragment}
        enter="transition ease-out duration-200"
        enterFrom="opacity-0 translate-y-1"
        enterTo="opacity-100 translate-y-0"
        leave="transition ease-in duration-150"
        leaveFrom="opacity-100 translate-y-0"
        leaveTo="opacity-0 translate-y-1"
      >
        <Menu.Items
          static
          className="origin-top-left absolute left-0 mt-2 w-full max-w-md rounded-3xl shadow-lg bg-white ring-1 ring-gray-900/5 focus:outline-none z-50"
        >
          <div className="p-4">
            <input
              onChange={handleSearchChange}
              className="block w-full px-4 py-2 mb-4 text-gray-800 border rounded-md border-gray-300 focus:outline-none"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Search assignees"
              autoComplete="off"
            />
            {filteredUsers.map((user, index) => (
              <Menu.Item key={index}>
                {({ active }) => (
                  <a
                    href="#"
                    className="group relative flex gap-x-6 rounded-lg p-4 hover:bg-gray-50 cursor-pointer focus:outline-none"
                    onClick={(e) => {
                      // e.preventDefault();
                      // handleAssigneeSelect(assignee);
                    }}
                  >
                    <span className="font-semibold text-gray-900">{user}</span>
                  </a>
                )}
              </Menu.Item>
            ))}
          </div>
        </Menu.Items>
      </Transition>
    </Menu>
  );
};

export default DropdownWithSearch;

UserAssignForm component
import Card from "components/card";
import { useState } from 'react';
import DropdownWithSearch from './DropdownWithSearch';

export default function UserAssignForm() {
    const [selectedAssignee, setSelectedAssignee] = useState('');
    const userList = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'David', 'Eve', 'Frank', 'Grace', 'Hank', 'Ivy', 'Jack'];

    return (
        <Card extra={"mb-3 w-full h-full px-6 pb-6 sm:overflow-x-auto reletive"}>
            <div className="relative flex items-center justify-between pt-4">
                <div className="text-xl font-bold text-navy-700 dark:text-white">
                    Assign Users
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="mt-8 overflow-x-scroll xl:overflow-x-hidden">
                <div className="mt-5 mb-5 grid h-full grid-cols-1 gap-5 md:grid-cols-2">
                    <div className="flex justify-center flex-row pl-3 pt-1">
                        <DropdownWithSearch
                        users = {userList}/>
                        <input
                            disabled={true}
                            type="text"
                            id="assigneeInput"
                            placeholder="Selected Assignee"
                            value={selectedAssignee}
                            onChange={(e) => setSelectedAssignee(e.target.value)}
                            className={`cursor-not-allowed ml-4 w-100 flex h-12 items-center justify-center rounded-xl border bg-white/0 p-3 text-sm outline-none `}
                        />
                    </div>
                    {/*...*/}
                </div>
                <div className="flex justify-center">
                    <button
                        className="linear px-10 rounded-xl bg-brand-500 py-3 text-base font-medium text-white transition duration-200 hover:bg-brand-600 active:bg-brand-700 dark:bg-brand-400 dark:text-white dark:hover:bg-brand-300 dark:active:bg-brand-200"
                    // onClick={handleSubmit}
                    >
                        Assign
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Card>
    );
}

I'm aware that we need to settle the position of the dropdown to absolute and it's popping out from the nearest upper relative div component. Although tailwind classes are settled it didn't work for me.

Did you try 'use client'?

After removing a few of overflow-related tailwind classes, a drop down popped out from the card.

You need to add overflow-visible tailwind class (docs) to the Menu to allow the popout to extend outside the box of the Menu.
